# NullPointerException - Replacing fragment in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace an existing fragment with another fragment. I am using FrameLayout, so that I can swap fragments.

I have to set some data to the new fragment, before showing it. But, I am getting a NullPointerException.

I am pretty new to Fragments, so please help me with this. I have looked at other Questions on SO, but, I couldn't solve my problem

Logcat :::

```
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at com.xx.xxx.wallet.WalletNotRedeemedFragment.setParameters(WalletNotRedeemedFragment.java:29)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at com.xx.xxx.wallet.WalletListActivity.onWalletListItemClick(WalletListActivity.java:70)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at com.xx.xxx.wallet.WalletListFragment$1.onItemClick(WalletListFragment.java:108)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-14 19:15:08.577: E/AndroidRuntime(10726):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please look at the code below...

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("imagepath", imagePath);
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    bundle.putString("desc", desc);

    WalletNotRedeemedFragment frag = new WalletNotRedeemedFragment();
    frag.setParameters(bundle);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.wallet_detail_container, frag).commit();
```

WalletNotRedeemed.java

```
public class WalletNotRedeemedFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet_not_redeemed,
                container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void setParameters(Bundle bundle) {
    // Null Pointer Exception here...
        TextView title = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.textview_coupon_title_nr);
        title.setText(bundle.getString("title"));

        TextView desc = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.textview_coupon_description_nr);
        desc.setText(bundle.getString("desc"));

        ImageView image = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.imageview_coupon_image_nr);
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imagepath")));

    }

}
```

From what I understood, by looking at other questions, is that the fragment is not loaded yet, and hence I get a NullPointerException, when I am trying to access the TextView, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Your help is much appreciated.. thanks!!!

---

Answer :::

I think, i got it to work.. but, it may not be the best way...

Here is what i have done...

```
public class WalletNotRedeemedFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    TextView title, desc;
    ImageView image;

    String strTitle, strDesc, strImage;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet_not_redeemed,
                container, false);

        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_coupon_title_nr);
        title.setText(strTitle);

        desc = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textview_coupon_description_nr);
        desc.setText(strDesc);

        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview_coupon_image_nr);
        image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(strImage));

        return view;
    }

    public void setParameters(Bundle bundle) {

        strTitle = bundle.getString("title");
        strDesc = bundle.getString("desc");
        strImage = bundle.getString("imagepath");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because **onCreateView()** method your *view* returned.

In ***setParameters*** method you have referenced ***getView()*** to find id of your UI elements.

So change

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet_not_redeemed,
            container, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) view .findViewById(
            R.id.textview_coupon_title_nr);


    TextView desc = (TextView) view .findViewById(
            R.id.textview_coupon_description_nr);


    ImageView image = (ImageView) view ).findViewById(
            R.id.imageview_coupon_image_nr);

    return view;
}
```

And in setParameters methos:

```
public void setParameters(Bundle bundle) {
// Null Pointer Exception here...

    title.setText(bundle.getString("title"));


    desc.setText(bundle.getString("desc"));


    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imagepath")));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I have made it to work, as i could, it may not be the best, but for now, i am working with it..

Comment: Sorry but now see my updated answer line by line... before  i have called title.setText(bundle.getString("title"));


    desc.setText(bundle.getString("desc"));


    image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imagepath"))); also in onCreateView() method..

Answer (score 0):

declare all view fields in OnCreateView method

```
  TextView title;
  TextView desc;
  ImageView image;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet_not_redeemed,
            container, false);

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.textview_coupon_title_nr);

    desc = (TextView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.textview_coupon_description_nr);

    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(
            R.id.imageview_coupon_image_nr);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the NullPointerException when trying to set text in setParameters method...

Comment: @VamsiChalla can you show me a line num 29 where error happens

Comment: I commented that in the question.. in setParameters method.. while trying to access TextView

Comment: @VamsiChalla please check that R.id.textview_coupon_title_nr is in layout R.layout.fragment_wallet_not_redeemed

Comment: I edited my question, with what I have done to make it work.. thanks for your help...